# How to convert a Google JWT into a Oauth2 token for the various APIs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth, oauth-2.0

I have a server to server style application running in Node.JS which needs access to Google Docs.   I am able to get a JWT token back from Google, but can't figure out how to exchange it for an OAUTH2 token to be used with the various Google APIs.  The OAuth 2.0 Playground isn't any help either, it doesn't recognize the string  JWT token either...

Sample Token Received: ya29.NgECxOUI6NICe_ow3C3iLyFviklSB5mW_ugMh0LADLjupr4fuGuih9UZHHCpHoAdhP7-JeBWZH-PCg

When I run this and get the above token, the error I receive back from Google is:
  { [Error: Incorrect token type.] code: 400, type: 'invalid_grant' }

Here is my code:

```
/ Code to Obtain OAUTH2 credentials to access google drive in Node.JS 
//
// To install googleapis --> npm install googleapis --save
var googleapis = require('googleapis');
// To install JWT Support --> npm install google-oauth-jwt
var googleAuth = require('google-oauth-jwt');
// To install Google Drive, npm install google-drive
var drive = googleapis.drive('v2');
var OAuth2 = googleapis.auth.OAuth2;

// variables to use to use to get initial identification token
var EMAIL = 'MyEmailAddressForServices@developer.gserviceaccount.com',
    KEYFILE = 'C:/GoogleWork/key.pem',
    SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file';

// Variables to use to obtain Oauth2 authorization
var CLIENT_ID = 'XXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    CLIENT_SECRET = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    REDIRECT_URL = 'http://localhost';

    googleAuth.authenticate({email: EMAIL, keyFile: KEYFILE, scopes: [SCOPE]},
        function(err, token) {

        if (err) {
          console.log('ERROR: ' + err);
          return;
          }
          else {
            console.log('Token Received: ' + token);
            GetToken(token);
            }
        });

var GetToken = function(token) {
      var auth = new OAuth2(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, REDIRECT_URL);
      auth.getToken(token, function(err, Oauth_Tokens) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Error while trying to retrieve token: ', err);
        return;
      }
      auth.credentials = Oauth_Tokens;
      console.log("Tokens: " + auth.credentials)
      //upload();
      });
    }
```

Any help would be most appreciated!
Thanks, Jeff

Comment: Just to clarify.. the actual credentials above have been xxx ed out for obvious privacy reasons.  To run this code fragment requires substitution of own values...

Comment: "ya29.NgECxOUI6..." is an access token

Comment: Thanks!  Using the token from the googleAuthenticate worked properly...   googleDrive(token).files().get(ListFiles) actually does a file listing... So all good... !  Thanks for your help... BTW:  I can see why you are so fond of the libraries, it seems that almost every node related example is out of date relative to its libraries... Looks like things are still evolving...